# combine samples of supersets to get a reservoir sample of the subset

Tags: sampling, software

Here's some background before my question (Bear with me! :D)

I am working on a data pipeline that deals with a massive input log dataset; instead of saving the full input log, current version of this pipeline captures a reservoir sample of the input log over a certain set of fields; e.g. say we are capturing reservoir samples for columns C1, C2 of the log with sample count of 10K.

The pipeline is very resource-intense (burns a lot of CPU) and having us explore ways of cutting down costs of this and other related computations. We have a badass in-memory compute engine that is super efficient with many things, but with this input dataset, it runs into 2 challenges -

1. The **approach to building [reservoir samples](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling) over C1, C2** in this compute engine requires **reading the entire input dataset** - causing obvious `**out-of-memory (OOM)**` failures
2. In concept, we could **break the input log into "segments" based on `C1, C2`** values, so the in-memory compute engine *processes a few segments at a time*, and gets around the OOM problem. However, the *resulting distribution has **terrible skew** (coefficient of variation > 20)* - this skew hurts the logging application (critical process) badly and is unacceptable
3. However, if we split the input log by **`C1, C2, C3, C4`** i.e. add a few more columns to the "key" used to break the input log by - the resulting distribution is a lot more uniform (coefficient of variation drops to around 6) - at which point the performance hit to logging is pretty low

**Stats question :)**

**`Is it possible to sample the superset C1, C2, C3, C4 to get a reservoir sample of the subset C1, C2?`**

Comment: I think you are more likely to obtain meaningful answers if you edit your question and present it as a sampling problem in terms that everyone will understand - not just technical people working with AWS' data pipeline.  Can you more generally describe what a "data reservoir" is and why you are trying to sample from it?  Many of the sampling statisticians here, have probably never worked with AWS.

Comment: Thanks @StatsStudent! This isn’t on or related to AWS.

Comment: I see, @Bi Act.  Even more reason to clarify some of the purely non-statistical and perhaps overly technical terms that appear in your post.

Comment: Sorry not sure what happened there with my comment there - reposting my comment

Comment: Thanks @StatsStudent! This isn’t on/related to AWS. By ‘reservoir_sampling’, I meant :) https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling since like I said the input dataset is massive & we wanted a sample representative of input distribution while ensuring rare events are at least rarely seen. I can rephrase specifics in the question - but overall this seems like an exercise in sampling/probability/algorithms  - how do you build a reservoir sample for a set of ‘columns’ from samples you collect over a ‘superset of those columns’? ‘Columns’ in this case refers to fields in the input dataset

Comment: Thanks, @Bi Act.  I'll take a read over this and think about this some.  This sounds very similar to what sampling statisticians might call Bernoulli Sampling.